# How to change unmanagedBase according to crossScalaVersions in sbt

Tags: sbt

I have to use different unmanaged jar files depending on the version of Scala being used.  It is possible to do this one Scala version at a time with a built.sbt like

```
val defaultScalaVersion = "2.12.4"

scalaVersion := defaultScalaVersion // because I can't figure out how to read value

val majorMinor = {
  val versionRegex = "(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)".r
  val versionRegex(major, minor, update) = defaultScalaVersion

  major + "." + minor
}

unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / ("lib-" + majorMinor)
```

However, if I need to publish for two different versions using something like

```
crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.11", "2.12.4")
```

of course my majorMinor and unmanagedBase do not get changed.  How can this be arranged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the current major/minor version of Scala with `scalaBinaryVersion.value` and use it directly:

```
unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / s"lib-${scalaBinaryVersion.value}"
```

You can also use [`CrossVersion.partialVersion`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/api/sbt/librarymanagement/CrossVersion$.html#partialVersion(s:String):Option[(Long,Long)]) to extract major/minor components of the version. So in case you want a different formatting of the version you could adapt your current solution:

```
lazy val majorMinor = Def.setting {
  CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value) match {
    case Some((major, minor)) => s"${major}-${minor}"
  }
}

unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / s"lib-${majorMinor.value}"
```

Notice that to be able to use `.value` in the `majorMinor` value definition, you need to use the `Def.setting` macro (or `Def.task` if you're referring to a task).

Comment: So far, so good.  It not only seems to works, but lets me know what parts of the documentation I need to look more closely at.  Thanks!